# Is there a more efficient way to structure this age-group based z-score calculation in Swift?

Tags: swift, calculator

I'm a total beginner with Swift and programming in general. I've figured out a way to code a z score calculator with different mean (M) and standard deviation (SD) values based on different age bands.  However, I'm going to be repeating this code a lot in an app I'm trying to build and I don't want to develop bad habits, so I was hoping to get some feedback about whether there would be a better/more efficient way to structure this.  I'm sure this will be pretty quickly apparent just looking at, but basically user inputs age, is assigned to an 'age class', and their score on a quiz (not coded out here) is transformed into a z-score based on M and SD data specific to their age group.  Any comments or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
var age:(Int)!

var ageClass:(String)!

var TestScore: (Double)!

age = 63

TestScore = 28

if (age <= 17) {ageClass = "ACInvalid"}
else if (age <= 35) {ageClass = "AC1"}
else if (age <= 50) {ageClass = "AC2"}
else if (age <= 60) {ageClass = "AC3"}
else if (age <= 70) {ageClass = "AC4"}
else if (age <= 80) {ageClass = "AC5"}
else if (age <= 109) {ageClass = "AC6"}
else {ageClass = "ACInvalid"}

//screen for ACInvalid
if (ageClass == "ACInvalid") {"Invalid Age Range"}
else {

let TestScoreM: [String:Double] = ["AC1": 35.7, "AC2": 33.5, "AC3": 31.2, "AC4": 
29.4, "AC5": 26.1, "AC6": 22.1]

let TestScoreSD: [String:Double] = ["AC1": 4.1, "AC2": 4.7, "AC3": 5.3, "AC4": 6.4,
"AC5": 8.1, "AC6": 9.7]

var TestScoreZ = (TestScore - TestScoreM[ageClass]!)/TestScoreSD[ageClass]!
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use implicitly unwrapped optionals for your variables (or mutable variables in this case). Just say, for example `let age = 63`, `let testScore = 28.0`, `let age : String` (you can defer initialisation of constants).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can try with an enum, Swift have very powerful enums !

Take a closer look at my code, it does the same than yours, but using the powerfulness and the safeness of Swift :

```
enum AgeClass {
  case AC1, AC2, AC3, AC4, AC5, AC6

  static func from(age: Int) -> AgeClass? {
    if (age <= 17) {
        return nil
    }
    else if (age <= 35) {
        return .AC1
    }
    else if (age <= 50) {
        return .AC2
    }
    else if (age <= 60) {
        return .AC3
    }
    else if (age <= 70) {
        return .AC4
    }
    else if (age <= 80) {
        return .AC5
    }
    else if (age <= 109) {
        return .AC6
    }

    return nil
  }

  var mean: Double {
    switch self {
    case .AC1:
        return 35.7
    case .AC2:
        return 33.5
    case .AC3:
        return 31.2
    case .AC4:
        return 29.4
    case .AC5:
        return 26.1
    case .AC6:
        return 22.1
    }
  }

  var standardDeviation: Double {
    switch self {
    case .AC1:
        return 4.1
    case .AC2:
        return 4.7
    case .AC3:
        return 5.3
    case .AC4:
        return 6.4
    case .AC5:
        return 8.1
    case .AC6:
        return 9.7
    }
  }
}

let age = 63
guard let ageClass = AgeClass.from(age: age) else {
    fatalError("AgeClass is invalid")
}

let testScore: Double = 28
let testScoreZ = testScore - ageClass.mean/ageClass.standardDeviation
```

Comment: A better way of handling invalid input would be to simply make `from(age: Int)` return an optional, rather than having a special "invalid" case. That way you can dispense with the default 0 returns and the caller chooses how they want to deal with invalid input when unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to this. My preferred choice is to define 2 classes: one define the age class and another containing the reference data. This way you can load the `ReferenceData` from a file or Core Data instead of hard coding them into the program:

```
enum AgeClass : Int {
    case ac1
    case ac2
    case ac3
    case ac4
    case ac5
    case ac6
    case invalid

    init(age: Int) {
        switch age {
        case 18...35:
            self = .ac1
        case 36...50:
            self = .ac2
        case 51...60:
            self = .ac3
        case 61...70:
            self = .ac4
        case 71...80:
            self = .ac5
        case 81...109:
            self = .ac6
        default:
            self = .invalid
        }
    }
}

struct ReferenceData {
    static var mean: [AgeClass : Double] = [
        .ac1: 35.7,
        .ac2: 33.5,
        .ac3: 31.2,
        .ac4: 29.4,
        .ac5: 26.1,
        .ac6: 22.1
    ]
    static var standardDeviation: [AgeClass : Double] = [
        .ac1: 4.1,
        .ac2: 4.7,
        .ac3: 5.3,
        .ac4: 6.4,
        .ac5: 8.1,
        .ac6: 9.7
    ]
}

let age = 63
let testScore = 28.0

// Example
let ageClass = AgeClass(age: age)
if let mean = ReferenceData.mean[ageClass],
    let stddev = ReferenceData.standardDeviation[ageClass] {
    let testScoreZ = (testScore - mean) / stddev
    print(testScoreZ)
}
```